# Import "docx" could not be resolved error in Python project in Visual Studio

Tags: python, python-docx

I am new to python and I tried to use docx module to automate some basic stuff.

I have installed python:

[image]

I have installed pip:

[image]

I have installed docx module using command:

> pip install python-docx

instead of:

> pip install docx

because I read that it install legacy version of that module.

Proof that I have docx installed:

[image]

Proof that I don't have legacy version istalled:

[image]

And even so when I code using Visual Studio it shows me:

[image]

And when I debug it shows me:

[image]

My full code is below but I don't think it is helpful in any way. What can I do to run it? Thank you in advance.

```
import os
from docx import Documents

# Set the directories
src_dir = "documents"
dst_dir = "output"

# Iterate through the files in the source directory
for file in os.listdir(src_dir):

# Check if the file is a .docx file
if file.endswith(".docx"):
    
    # Open the .docx file using the Document class from the docx module
    doc = Document(os.path.join(src_dir, file))
    
    # Iterate through the tables in the document
    for table in doc.tables:
        
        # Create a new .docx file in the output directory
        new_doc = Document()
        
        # Add the table to the new document
        new_doc.add_table(table)
        
        # Save the new document to the output directory
        new_doc.save(os.path.join(dst_dir, file))
    
    # Break out of the loop after the first .docx file is found
    break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the python version you use for building the script is the same as the python version you use to run `pip install docx` or `python-docx`.

When you run `pip install ...` it will show the part to the python version which is being installed, use it to compare with the python version which show when you build/debug the script.

Example of logging when installing a library (it has `python310` -> it is being installed on Python 3.10)

```
Requirement already satisfied: loguru in c:\users\ntgr\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (0.6.0)
```

Example of logging when running a script (it has `Python310` -> it is running on Python 3.10):

```
PS D:\_PROJECT\bot_hunter_5.0\hunter-5-0-bot>  & 'C:\Python310\python.exe' 'c:\Users\NTGR\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugp
y\launcher' '56421' '--' 'd:\_PROJECT\bot_hunter_5.0\hunter-5-0-bot\bot.py
```

In case the versions are mismatched, you can change the build/run python version by clicking the version which is located at the bottom-right in the VSCode (as in the image below)

[image]

Or specifying the python version when using pip install.